Demander de/à faire quelque chose
Selon Google Ngrams, les deux apparaissent avec plus ou moins la même fréquence, mais je me demande s'il n'y a pas une différence entre leurs usages ? Y a-t-il des circonstances où je devrais utiliser l'un plutôt que l'autre ?
Autrement dit, y a-t-il une différence entre « demander de » et « demander à » [faire quelque chose] ?

Trouvé ici :
On dit demander à quand l'infinitif qui suit se rapporte à la personne qui demande.

Je demande à avoir plus de responsabilités.
Il a demandé à voyager plus souvent.

On dit demander de quand l'infinitif qui suit se rapporte à une autre personne que celle qui fait la demande.

Elle m'a demandé de faire plus attention. → Ici, c'est Elle qui demande, et moi (m') qui doit faire attention.
Je lui ai demandé de réfléchir à mon augmentation. → Ici, c'est Moi (J') qui demande, et elle ou lui (lui) qui doit réfléchir.

De plus, "demander à" est plus soutenu, et plutôt rare dans le langage courant de nos jours. On dira "J'ai demandé de l'eau" plutôt que "J'ai demandé à avoir de l'eau".

Ah merci, c'était un peu nuancé alors.
